# Why doesn't JSON parsing fail with completely different type passed to Decode()?

Tags: json, go, jsonparser

I have the following data structures which I'd like to parse from an API:

```
type OrderBook struct {
    Pair       string           `json:"pair"`
    UpdateTime int64            `json:"update_time"`
}

type depthResponse struct {
    Result OrderBook `json:"result"`
    // doesn't matter here
    //Cmd    string              `json:"-"`
}
```

and when I parse the following:

```
data := `{"error":{"code":"3016","msg":"交易对错误"},"cmd":"depth"}`
```

It doesn't fail. Why?

Full source code ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XfX3ZSMBvjh))

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type OrderBook struct {
    Pair       string           `json:"pair"`
    UpdateTime int64            `json:"update_time"`
}

type depthResponse struct {
    Result OrderBook `json:"result"`
}

func main() {
    data := `{"error":{"code":"3016","msg":"交易对错误"},"cmd":"depth"}`
    r := strings.NewReader(data)

    var resp depthResponse
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&resp); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("We should end up here: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", resp)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour of `Decode` (as documented in the `Unmarshal` function):

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

> By default, object keys which don't have a corresponding struct field are ignored.

You can however use the `DisallowUnknownFields()` function (as described in the docs as well) to have it fail if the input JSON has fields not contained in the destination struct.

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(r)
dec.DisallowUnknownFields()
```

In that case, you'll get an error as you expect.

Modified playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/A0f6dxTXV34

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was missing! It's a pity that `.DisallowUnknownFields()` doesn't return `json.Decoder` to chain those calls.